# i need to create a function in python displaying a form where we can submit data to a database table (using the methods get and post)

Tags: python, html, database, forms, flask

that's my python code:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request , jsonify, url_for, redirect
import sqlite3

app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/create', methods=['get', 'post'])
def create():
    if request.method == 'get':
        return render_template('form.html')
    elif request.method == 'post':
        con = sqlite3.connect('televtar.db')
        cur = con.cursor()

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO user VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (request.form.get('email'), request.form.get('username'), request.form.get('name')))
        cur.close()
        con.commit()
        
        return ("done!")
```

The error message is the following:

> TypeError: The view function for 'create' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

it tried to remove the post and database part of the code but it still would not work, i checked the syntax and the connection to the database (it was successful with other routes and functions) I've implemented the almost same function with another program and it worked, i can't find the problem with this one

Comment: `GET` and `POST`, not `get` and `post`